# Calculate office hours in python

Tags: python

I have a csv with data, and I would like to calculate the time differences depends on id but without using pandas.

I have a data like:

| id | type | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | out | 2023-01-01T08:01:28.000Z |
| 1 | in | 2023-02-01T08:01:28.000Z |
| 2 | in | 2023-02-01T09:04:16.000Z |
| 2 | out | 2023-02-01T012:01:28.000Z |
| 1 | out | 2023-02-01T013:34:15.000Z |

The main goal is to get the hours difference for the same id that are in the February month.

Expected result:

| id | spent time in office | day in month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 04:32:47 | 2023-02-01 |
| 2 | 02:57:12 | 2023-02-01 |

I colledted the February data:

```
import datetime;

with open('data.csv', mode ='r') as file:    
        csvFile = csv.DictReader(file)
        list_of_dict = list(csvFile)
        startDate = datetime.date(2023,2,1)
        endDate = datetime.date(2023,2,28)
        februaryList = []

        for d in list_of_dict:
            convertedDateFromCsv = datetime.datetime.strptime(d['event_time'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ").date()
            if startDate <= convertedDateFromCsv <= endDate:
                februaryList.append(d)
                
        for i in februaryList:
```

But I am stucked do not know how to collect the dates for the same id and in the same time eval them to get the difference. Should I use multiple for loop for this ?

Any help would appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the desired result based on your sample data.

Comment: @PM77-1 thank you for the feedback, i edited my question.

Comment: Why don't you want to use pandas?

Comment: @Xukrao I know it would be better to use pandas, but the online tasks said i should only use python and built-in libraries.

Comment: @mynameiszsofia Ah, so it's an educational exercise to practice program logic. I understand. I hope however that the pandas library will also be covered at some point in later lessons, since for tasks like these it enables more concise syntax as well as superior execution speed (which of course doesn't really matter for an input data table as small as the one in your example, but if you would have for example a few million data rows, well then it would already be a different story).

Comment: What is the expected output when there is missing input? Like "in without out",  "out without in", repeated sequence of in/repeated of out?

Comment: shouldn't` id 1 work hours be 05:32:47?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the csv

```py
your_data = """id   type    time
1   out 2023-01-01T08:01:28.000Z
1   in  2023-02-01T08:01:28.000Z
2   in  2023-02-01T09:04:16.000Z
2   out 2023-02-01T12:01:28.000Z
1   out 2023-02-01T13:34:15.000Z"""

#2023-02-01T012:01:28.000Z
#2023-02-010T13:34:15.000Z are not valid dates
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(your_data), sep='\t')
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Start from here

```py
import datetime
import csv

date_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
total_time = {}
feb = datetime.datetime.strptime('2023-02', '%Y-%m').month


file_path = 'data.csv'
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    # Create a CSV reader
    csv_file = csv.DictReader(f)
    list_of_dict = list(csv_file)


for d in list_of_dict:
  w_id = d['id']
  dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(d['time'], date_format).date()
  d_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(d['time'], date_format)

  if d_time.month == feb:

    if not total_time.get(w_id):
      total_time[w_id] = {"date": None,"last_in": None, "last_out": None, "work_hour_s": 0. , 'work_hour_string': '' }

    update_time = total_time[w_id]
    update_time['date'] = dt
    if d['type'] == 'in':
      update_time['last_in'] = d_time
    if d['type'] == 'out':
      update_time['last_out'] = d_time

    if update_time['last_out'] and update_time['last_in']:
      if update_time['last_out'] > update_time['last_in']:
        work_hour_s = update_time['last_out'] - update_time['last_in']
        update_time['work_hour_s'] += work_hour_s.seconds

        up_time = int(update_time['work_hour_s'])
        hours, remainder = divmod(up_time, 3600)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)

        formatted_duration = f"{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}"
        update_time['work_hour_string'] = formatted_duration

total_time
```

it will output

```py
{'1': {'date': datetime.date(2023, 2, 1),
  'last_in': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 1, 8, 1, 28),
  'last_out': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 1, 13, 34, 15),
  'work_hour_s': 19967.0,
  'work_hour_string': '05:32:47'},
 '2': {'date': datetime.date(2023, 2, 1),
  'last_in': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 1, 9, 4, 16),
  'last_out': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 1, 12, 1, 28),
  'work_hour_s': 10632.0,
  'work_hour_string': '02:57:12'}}
```

1. Are the dates in this csv ordered? If not this is up to you!
2. What do you expect to see if there is missing data? Some one checked in but did not check-out, some one checked-in in sequence, checked-out in sequence, things like that. Sanitizing is up to you too.

Answer (score -1):

You can use dict where key is id and values is list of dates

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).